# Can you help to prove this equation by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Can you help to prove by induction that $(9^n - 1)(n^3 + 3n^2+ 2n + 6)$ is divisible by $48$ .

I know that I can assume that it holds for $n$, and try to prove than it holds for $(n+1)$.
That is where I got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

let $T(n)=(9^n-1)(n^3+3n^2+2n+6)$ and $$48|T(n)$$ we have to show that $48|T(n+1)$
now compute $$T(n+1)-T(n)$$ and this is $$(9^n-1)\cdot 3(n+1)(2+n)+8\cdot 9^n(n+4)(n^2+2n+3)$$

Comment: why T(n)-T(n+1)?

Comment: you know that $$48|T(n)$$ and if the difference is divisible by $48$ then must also $48|T(n+1)$

Answer (score 0):

$$9^{n+1}-1=9\cdot9^n-1=8\cdot9^n+9^n-2\equiv9^n-1\mod 8.$$

and

$$(n+1)^3 + 3(n+1)^2+ 2(n+1) + 6=n^3+6n^2+11n+12\\
=3n^2+9n+6+n^3+3n^2+2n+6\\
=3(n+1)(n+2)+n^3+3n^2+2n+6.
$$

Then one of $n+1$, $n+2$ is even and

$$(n+1)^3 + 3(n+1)^2+ 2(n+1) + 6=n^3+3n^2+2n+6\mod 6.$$

Finally, the base cases show that $9^n-1$ is a multiple of $8$ and $n^3+3n^2+2n+6$ a multiple of $6$.

Comment: how did you get that one of n+!, n+2 is even?

Comment: @BellePepper: try with a few numbers.